# String regex split printout contains fewer lines than expected?

Tags: java, regex, string, split

We have the following code

```
String quote = "aba*abaa**aabaa***";
String[] words = quote.split("a\\**");
for (String word : words) {
  System.out.println(word);
}
```

The regular expression means exactly one 'a' character, followed by zero or more '*' characters

This means that the string is tokenized as follows: a, b, a*, a, b, a, a**, a, a, b, a, a*** (this can be also double checked using Pattern/Matcher classes)

However, the above System.out.println() is producing the following printout: (empty line), b, (empty line), b, (3 empty lines), b

What is not clear here, why is only one empty line between the first and second 'b' (there are two tokens in between), and why are three empty lines between the second and third 'b' (there are four tokens in between)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Between the first and second `b`, we have `ba*ab`. The delimiter pattern used in the splitting method would match `a*`, followed by an empty string, then it matches `a` followed by `b`. The empty string is displayed as the empty line by the `System.out.println()`.

Similarly, between the second and third `b`, the substring is `baa**aab`. Therefore, the delimiter matches `a`, then an empty string, then `a**` followed by another empty string, then `a` followed by a third empty string, and finally another `a` followed by a `b`. Therefore the total number of lines is 3.

```
ba          a**           a              ab
     ^^^           ^^^           ^^^
  emptystring   emptystring   emptystring
```

In order to get the list as specified, `a, b, a*, a, b, a, a**, a, a, b, a, a***`, one solution is to construct the list using a `Matcher`:

```
String quote = "aba*abaa**aabaa***";    
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("a\\**");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(quote);
List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
int start = 0;
while(matcher.find()) {
    if(start < matcher.start()) {
        words.add(quote.substring(start, matcher.start()));
    }
    words.add(matcher.group());
    start = matcher.end();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If there are `k` tokes, there should be `k - 1` empty lines, so it works as expected. Let's take a look at an example: `ba*ab`, which is tokenized as `b, a*, a, b`. There is only one thing between two separators, so it gives only one empty String.